# How to output a variables objects into multiple different lines in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops

I can't figure out how to output [Write-Host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) into multiple different lines.

My code is as follows:

```
$Identification = 123, 234, 543, 213
$Num = 8999, 2342, 1238, 9993

Write-Host "The ID is $ID, and the Num is $Num"
```

The problem I am having is that the output will list all the numbers and IDs in one string or sentence when I need the output to each have its' own line. For instance:

> The ID is 123, and the Num is 8999.

Consider that each `$Num` is correlated with each `$Identification`.

Comment: Using this "multi-purpose" [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule), you might do this: `$Identification |Join $Num |Foreach-Object { "The ID is {0}, and the Num is {1}" -f @($_) }`

Answer (score 1):

> Consider that each $Num is correlated with each $Identification.

Then you'll probably want to construct objects that tie them together:

```
$objects = for($i = 0; $i -lt $Num.Length; $i++){
  # here we construct a new object with the two correlated property values
  [PSCustomObject]@{ Num = $Num[$i]; ID = $Identification[$i] }
}
```

Now you can iterate over the `$objects` array and write them to the screen one at a time:

```
foreach($object in $objects) {
  Write-Host "The ID is $($object.ID), and the Num is $($object.Num)"`
}
```

---

Of course you can skip that step and use a `for` loop directly:

```
$objects = for($i = 0; $i -lt $Num.Length; $i++){
  $N = $Num[$i]
  $ID = $Identification[$i]
  Write-Host "The ID is $ID, and the Num is $N"
}
```

---

A third option is to use the LINQ [`Zip()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) to construct objects by "zipping" the two input lists together:

```
$objects = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  [int[]]$Num,
  [int[]]$Identification,
  [System.Func[int,int,psobject]]{
    param($n,$id)

    [pscustomobject]@{Num=$n;ID=$id}
})
```

At which point you can iterate over the resultant `$objects` array like in the first example